# documentum DQL command exec count_sessions - what means columns "hot_list_size", "warm_list_size","cold_list_size"?

Tags: dql, documentum

I found undocumented DQL command in documentum (tested on D6.5)

`exec count_sessions`

what means columns "hot_list_size", "warm_list_size","cold_list_size" in output of this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hot_list_size refers to the number of active content server sessions, warm_list_size refers to the sessions that have been timed out on the server side, and cold_list_size is the number of free sessions. Reference: [post on the EMC Community site](https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-9929).

Comment: Reference link seems unavailable. Reference link on OpenText site is [here](https://support.opentext.com/csm?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0718339).